# Bokeh and Ipython interactors to control more than one plot element

Tags: jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I've been working with Bokeh server plots and Ipython integrators as described in the Bokeh documentation [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#id5).  I can get sliders to update parameters that move the intercept and slope of a single line but when I add code for another line of the plot that should also move in response to the same parameter changes only the first line changes. Consider:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import Range1d, ColumnDataSource
from ipywidgets import interact
output_notebook()

A = 300   # common intercept
b1 = 2    # slope line 1
b2 = 1/2  # slope line 2

x = np.linspace(0,500,100)
y0 = A - b1*x
y1 = A - b2*x

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y0=y0, y1=y1))
TOOLS = "resize,reset,save,box_select"
p = figure(title='Two moving lines',tools=TOOLS)
p.x_range = Range1d(0, 500)
p.y_range = Range1d(0, 500)
p.line('x', 'y0', line_width=3, color='red', source=source)
p.line('x', 'y1', line_width=3, source=source)

def f(A, b1, b2):
    source.data['y0'] = A - b1*x
    source.data['yl'] = A - b2*x
    source.push_notebook()

show(p)
```

This displays a plot with two lines. The following code will then display sliders for A, b1 and b2.

```
interact(f, A=(100,500,50), b1=(0.25,3,0.25), b2=(0.25,3,0.25) )
```

However moving slider A only moves the first line (though it should move both), slider b1 moves the first line, slider b2 moves nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: At the third line from the end: maybe a confusion between `y1` and `yl`?

Comment: That was it... sorry for the silly syntax error mistake!  I'm now tempted to delete this question as too localized.. But many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to fonts in your editor.  Your variable is actually "y1", as in the number "1", but your code in f() is setting "yl", as in the lowercase letter "l".  If you fix "yl" to "y1", then your code works.